# Other way to build bootstrap framework with "else if"?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, if

I have created a page for header.phtml I tried to change old design to new useful design with Bootstrap with my book. But I have a problem in two lines

> `<?php else: ?>`
>
> `<?php endif;?>`

My php file doesnt work at all. I tried to take it out, but I need them because if customer logged in he would see different links on it.

I putted my code under my comments

So my question, is there another way to do it? Create same page, but with different structure

---

```
<div id="topbar">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topbar_cmslinks') ?>
        </div>
        <div class="user-link col-md-4">
            <span class="welcome pull-left">
                <?php echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('header')->getWelcome() ?>
            </span>
            <ul class="list-inline pull-left">
                <li>
                    <a title="<?php echo $this->__('My Account') ?>" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('My Account') ?>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a title="Log Out" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/logout') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Logout') ?></a>
                </li>
                <?php else: ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/login/')?>">
                <?php echo $this->__('Login') ?></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/create/')?>">
                <?php echo $this->__('Create Account') ?></a>
                </li>
                <?php endif;?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't find your if statement. It should work, here is an example. You can also use regular php syntax.

```
<?php $user = Mage::getModel('customer/session')->isLoggedIn(); ?>
<?php if ($user) : ?>
<strong>user is logged in</strong>
<?php else: ?>
<strong>user not logged in</strong>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Regular syntax:

```
<?php $user = Mage::getModel('customer/session')->isLoggedIn(); ?>
<?php if ($user) { ?>
<strong>user is logged in</strong>
<?php } else { ?>
<strong>user not logged in</strong>
<?php } ?>
```

**update**

your code might not work becouse you use `<?php endif;?>` try putting a space between ; and ?> You also don't need the ;, just write it as `<?php endif ?>`

Comment: Thanks, that helped me, but I have found different glitch that brake my php code.
However, there are more glitches that I found

Comment: If your writing code i suggest you use a good IDE or a tool with syntax highlighting which can detect these problems. I always use Phpstorm with the Magicento plugin. Makes coding magento a whole lot easier.